# Photoshop Templates

Tags: templates, photoshop

Does anyone know any good tutorials for designing a website from a photoshop template?

Comment: Sorry, but this website is for programming-related questions only, and this isn't programming related.

Comment: Serach on google not here.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, SO isn't for photoshop. Perhaps that will exist as an option in the future. For now, I would suggest you check out the templates at http://www.templatemonster.com or http://www.themeforest.net

Check out "Photoshop Templates" on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=photoshop+templates) too.

Other Great Sites:

- [PSDTuts](http://psd.tutsplus.com/)
- [Smashing Magazine - Best of Photoshop Tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/01/10/adobe-photoshop-tutorials-best-of/)
- [Good Tutorials](http://www.good-tutorials.com/tutorials/photoshop)
- ["Web Layouts" on Tutorialized](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/Photoshop/Web-Layouts/1)
- [PhotoshopStar](http://www.photoshopstar.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some interesting sites googling "photoshop web template tutorial",

However i don't know about SO policy about links

-Lau